# Logfile or something of a shape

Tags: qgis-processing, log

I've a shape which was processed with the qgis geoalgorithm tool "eliminate sliver polygons".

My desire is to get a kind of logfile of this certain process. I need to know the whole calculations behind this.

I hope u can imagine what I want..

Comment: im not familiar with processing or programming...could this link be an answer? https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/python/plugins/fTools/tools/doEliminate.py